# Menus on global menu bar not showing, but are selected

Tags: 12.04, unity, menu

This seems to be a strange problem. Please refer to the attached screenshots. In the menu where I have clicked on Glipper, the menu is hidden behind the window. Only way to see the menu is to minimize all the windows.

Also, in the second screenshot I have clicked on the View Menu, and it doesnt show the menu. However, if I click on the space where the menu would have been, the items are activated. I was able to goto Full screen mode that way!

I also cannot open context menus in any application. But if I press the shortcut key, the action is performed.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS on a Lenovo G570. IIRC, It has been updated on 15th Jan, 830 AM IST.

[image: First Screenshot]

[image: Second Screenshot]

I was not able to find a bug report or anything, since I was not able to find the right words. Would gladly +1 the bug report if any.

Comment: What kind of desktop environment are you using? It appears not to be Unity to me. Also, what window manager are you using? Compiz, metacity, Kwin, etc.

Comment: Its the default, I have not made any changes to it. Just changed the theme from Ambiance to Radiance, and I think the icon pack using Ubuntu Tweak. `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns `Unity` and `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` returns `ubuntu`.